# angular 2 write a ngIf statement by output of a function

Tags: google-maps, angular, typescript

I am working with sebm angular 2 google maps library, I have a function of the zoomChange event like this: 
`<sebm-google-map (zoomChange)="testFunction($event)"></sebm-google-map>`

and in my component this is the function:

```
testFunction(e){
    console.log('test', e);
}
```

Want to write an ngIf statement to show a specific marker when zoom level is 18:

```html
<sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let clustermarker of clusters" 
                        (markerClick)="clustermarkerClicked()" 
                        [latitude]="clustermarker.latitude" 
                        [longitude]="clustermarker.longitude" 
                        [iconUrl]="clustermarker.icon">
</sebm-google-map-marker>
```

Than an other question is how do I chain an zoom in event to markerClick event

Answer (score 2):

Set a property to the zoom level

```
constructor(cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

testFunction(e){
    this.zoomLevel = e;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
    console.log('test', e);
}
```

Show the component when the zoom level matches:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="zoomLevel == 18">
  <sebm-google-map-marker *ngFor="let clustermarker of clusters" (markerClick)="clustermarkerClicked()" [latitude]="clustermarker.latitude" [longitude]="clustermarker.longitude" [iconUrl]="clustermarker.icon"></sebm-google-map-marker>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: is it new syntax [ngIf] or you only use it with a template? Why are you using a template tag?

Comment: It's only when used with `<template>` and I used `<template>` because there is already an `*ngFor` on the `<sebm-google-map-marker>` element and there can only be one structural directive at a time on one element.

Comment: You made a typo in the [ngIf]="zoomLevel", it works but only after a click it disappears. So when I zoom in from 18 to 17 it still shows the marker but than after a click it is hiding

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I updated my anwser. (`testFunction`). If the view doesn't update, it seems there is something running outside Angulars zone. Try to invoke change detection explicitly like shown above.

Comment: Do I also have to import it?

Comment: Yes, you need to import `ChangeDetectorRef`.

Comment: Uncaught Can't resolve all parameters for a: (a, b, a, Window, ?). Where the question mark is cdRef

Comment: Not sure what you did but never experienced any issues with injecting `ChangeDetectorRef` myself.

Comment: maybe I have an older version of angular where this is not implemented?

Comment: That's unchanged since at least 8 months.